# mysql query is not fetching all the elements from the table

Tags: php, mysql

it's just fetching the first element from the table.
Table name is categories which contains 2 columns : id, category

I cant understand why is it fetching just first row from the table.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT category FROM categories";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    //print_r($row);             
?>
```

Comment: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // do stuff }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **iterate** through the result set in order to retrieve **all** the rows.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print($row);
}
```

Also, stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking forward to using MySQLi.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in while loop :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you wrote `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` will get only one row. You have to use loop to get it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you call mysql_fetch_assoc just once, you'll get only the first row...

```
while(false !== $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using only does one record. 
Try. ..while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['category'];
  echo "
";
  }

Answer (score 0):

For retrieve result set Use loop as per your need

```
 foreach
```

Use when iterating through an array whose length is (or can be) unknown.
as

```
foreach($row as $val)
{
echo $val;
}
```

for

Use when iterating through an array whose length is set, or, when you need a counter.

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof($row);i++)
{
echo $row[$i];
}
```

while

Use when you're iterating through an array with the express purpose of finding, or triggering a certain flag.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $row['flag'];
}
```